# INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented but not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I have an app that uses MVVM pattern and implements INotifyPropertyChanged but it's not working. Basically when I choose a Wine from a list and click 'open', another usercontrol should load with all the details filled in.

I followed along with a pluralsight course and have tried to adapt it and create something of my own. I have gone through the source code of the pluralsight course and stack-overflow questions for many hours and just can't see what I'm missing. Going crazy here.. :(

After alot of searching, I know my databinding is working, because I can force an update to the target like so:

```
txtWijnNaam.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

I also tried adding the INotifyPropertyChanged to my Wine model class as well as the viewmodel but this didn't work. And it's also not used like this in the working source code of the pluralsight course so shouldn't be necessary.

The viewmodel I'm using:

```
class WineDetailViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly string _baseUri = "https://localhost/api/wines";
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public WineDetailViewModel()
    {
        _eventAggregator = EventAggregatorSingleton.Instance;
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<OpenWineDetailViewEvent>().Subscribe(OnOpenWineDetailView);
    }

    private void OnOpenWineDetailView(int wineId)
    {
        _wine = ApiHelper.GetApiResult<Wine>($"{ _baseUri}/{wineId}");
    }

    private Wine _wine;

    public Wine WineFull
    {
        get { return _wine; }
        set
        {
            _wine = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And the base class it inherits from, implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface:

```
class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Part of my Xaml file, I tried setting updateSourceTrigger like I saw on some answers here but this didn't help either:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WineGUI.View.WineDetailView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WineGUI.View"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:WineGUI.ViewModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:WineDetailViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<StackPanel>
    <Grid Margin="5">
        <TextBlock Text="Naam :" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="txtWijnNaam" Margin="5" Text="{Binding WineFull.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Jaar :" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="txtWijnYear" Margin="5" Text="{Binding WineFull.Year, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Prijs :" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

I do notice the OnPropertyChanged() method of my WineFull property is never called but I don't get why. The pluralsight course has an identical set-up (except for some naming of course) and it works just fine..

Any help would be much appreciated. If I need to add any more info or code, please let me know.

Comment: I'm new to SO when it comes to asking questions and try to follow all the rules and tips. So it would help if those who downvote also give me a reason so I can actually learn from it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the value of the backing field not the property so the OnPropertyChanged method is never called.

You can call OnPropertyChanged for the WineFull property in the OnOpenWineDetailView method:

```
private void OnOpenWineDetailView(int wineId)
{
    _wine = ApiHelper.GetApiResult<Wine>($"{ _baseUri}/{wineId}");
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WineFull));
}
```

Or you can use the property:

```
private void OnOpenWineDetailView(int wineId)
{
    WineFull= ApiHelper.GetApiResult<Wine>($"{ _baseUri}/{wineId}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Marked as accepted answer. I'm an idiot.. :) Was thinking of it as something so complicated while it was so simple.